# Spring+Hibernate+java :Connecting to multiple database after running application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbctemplate

If application is running and connected to Database-1. Through application **I want to copy certain data from one Database (it can be Database-1 on any other) to another database**. There can be 3-4 database. And **schema is exactly same for all the database**. ***Is it possible to do so?***
I have read about "**AbstractRoutingDataSource**" [here](http://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/). But I don't wan't to  connect to database during runtime. It should be after runtime.

my `spring-config.xml` contains bean for `JdbcTemplate`

```
<bean id="EnvJdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="envDataSource" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

I have created bean for envDataSource (database 1)

```
<bean id="envDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName"/>              
    <property name="url"/>
    <property name="username"/>
    <property name="password"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Do you mean Read Replication?

Comment: Nope. I have multiple entities in my db. So I want to copy certain entity from one db to another db through my app. And the db can be other than my connected db.

Comment: when you say copy, do you mean in real-time? as entities get created, updated, etc, the entities you require get written to the second DB?

Comment: entites are already there in one DB. I just want to coipy any existing entity from one to other.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you just need to create more beans, and inject them where needed, and call them when you need. This isn't that smart, but you don't need over engineer this.

```
<bean id="envDataSource1" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName"/>              
    <property name="url"/>
    <property name="username"/>
    <property name="password"/>
</bean>

<bean id="envDataSource2" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName"/>              
    <property name="url"/>
    <property name="username"/>
    <property name="password"/>
</bean>

<bean id="EnvJdbcTemplate1" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="envDataSource1" />
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="EnvJdbcTemplate2" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="envDataSource2" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Yes I know it will work this way.I can use only one template. I guess I tries using a map and passing values in real-time. It didn't work.

Comment: I thought of using multiple beans for diff DB and then passing their ref during runtime. So that I canneed to use one template every time.

Comment: <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource">
   <ref bean="envDataSource" />
  </property>
</bean>

Answer (score 0):

There is a built in feature in Hibernate to support multiple schemas/databases. find it [here](http://javabeginnerstutorial.com/hibernate/multi-tenancy-with-hibernate-4/)